# ChartJS2 in Ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic2, chart.js

I have created a new project and tried to implement charts using ChartJS2 [from this link](https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-chartjs2)

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { ChartModule } from 'ng2-chartjs2';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ChartModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="../node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
<!--<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>-->

<!-- Tried all three  -->
```

**home.ts**

```
...    
import { Chart } from 'ng2-chartjs2';
...
export class HomePage {

  ...
  labels: string[] = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];
  data: Chart.Dataset[] = [
    {
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
    borderWidth: 1
     } 
  ];
}
```

I'm getting an error

> chart.js:21 You must include Chart.js 2.0 Library in your index.html
>   in order for ng2-chartjs2 to work.

Github Repo - [Here is my full program with this error](https://github.com/darthranjith/Ionic2-Chart)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

Add a folder inside of your **src/assets** named **libs**, then copy **node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js** to **src/assets/libs**

Now go to your **index.html** file and remove the old reference to **chart.js** add this one:

`<script src="assets/libs/chart.bundle.js"></script>`

I have tried your project for some reason the index.html inside of www wasn't updated, maybe you need to add that reference there too.

Comment: The chart is working on browser but not in android device. Any advice? updated my repo. Check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I already posted an answer about the issue with the device on your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150362/ionic-2-ng2-chartjs2-working-on-browser-but-not-in-device/40156860#40156860