# Ionic 2 - ng2-chartjs2 working on browser but not in device

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng2-charts

I have managed to implement ng2-chartjs2 in my ionic2 application. It is perfectly working when i run it on browser (i.e ionic serve or ionic run android -l -c) but when i tried it on device (i.e ionic run android), it simply shows a blank page.

I have uploaded the working sample project [in my repo here](https://github.com/darthranjith/Ionic2-Chart)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Still expecting someone to clear this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the issue here is that the Chart.bundle.js isn't on the expected path on android build.

Add this:

```
var availablePlatforms = (process.env.CORDOVA_PLATFORMS ? process.env.CORDOVA_PLATFORMS.split(',') : []);

var filestocopy = [
  {"src/assets/libs/Chart.bundle.js": "platforms/android/assets/libs/Chart.bundle.js"}
];

for(var x=0; x<availablePlatforms.length; x++) {

  var currentPlatform = availablePlatforms[x].trim().toLowerCase();

  if (currentPlatform == 'android') {
    filestocopy.forEach(function(obj) {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        var val = obj[key];
        var srcfile = path.join(rootdir, key);
        var destfile = path.join(rootdir, val);
        var destdir = path.dirname(destfile);
        if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir)) {
          fs.createReadStream(srcfile).pipe(
              fs.createWriteStream(destfile));
        }
      });
    });

  }
}
```

At the end of your `hooks -> after_prepare -> 010_add_platform_class.js`, then change the script reference inside of your **index.html** to `<script src="assets/libs/Chart.bundle.js"></script>` (note: changed chart for Chart).

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect @camaron. Thanks again.

Comment: I have this problem with ios too. Too bad I can't try at work. Does it work with ios or have you only tried for android?

Comment: I tried this for ios but it does not work even though it has been copied across correctly.
let filestocopy_ios = [
  {"src/assets/libs/Chart.bundle.js": "platforms/ios/www/libs/Chart.bundle.js"}
];

Comment: @Mukus if you have a git repo, please give me the url and also the ionic version that you are using, check if the path where you should have the files is "platforms/ios/www/libs/Chart.bundle.js" maybe it has changed.

Comment: @camaron I got chartjs working, but without using ng2-chartjs.